# google sheet Networkday.intl

Tags: google-sheets, formula, array-formulas

I am currently looking for the number of working days deducting the holidays and the weekends. I'm using this formula right now.

```
 =NETWORKDAYS.INTL(E2,F2,1,Holidays!A1:A19)
```

putting the list of holidays on another sheet. It worked on the first cell,I enter the formula. However the numbers on the holidays range keeps on increasing, When I copy and paste into the next cell.

```
 =NETWORKDAYS.INTL(E3,F3,1,Holidays!A2:A20)
```

This is for the 2nd cell and for the 3rd cell,

```
 =NETWORKDAYS.INTL(E4,F4,1,Holidays!A3:A21)
```

I would like to ask if there is anything that I can do, When pasting the formula on each cell without moving the Holiday range. I tried entering the formula one by one and it worked. But, I am looking for an easier way for future use. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To lock a range use `$`

```
  =NETWORKDAYS.INTL(E2,F2,1,Holidays!A$1:A$19)
```

This will lock the rows. So if you drag fill down or copy paste down `1` and  `19` won't change. But if you drag fill to the right,A will become B and so on. 
To make a full lock, use `$` on both columns and rows.

```
 =NETWORKDAYS.INTL(E2,F2,1,Holidays!$A$1:$A$19)
```